# More efficient way to make a number memorisation program

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm working on a program that prints a random german word, then the user enters the numeral, if correct it adds one to score if not it does nothing. I'm still a beginner so its just lots of if statements, is there a way where i can just have a function with minimum numbers then the computer randomly puts them together while also being able to tell the right answer from the wrong ones?

How can i make a random german word generator without having to make an if statement for every number?

~Edit 1

```
start:
string zero = "Null", one = "Eins", two = "Zwei", three = "Drei", four = "Vier", five = "Funf";
int ans, score = 0;
srand(time(0));          
int x = rand() % 5;     
if (x == 0)
{
    cout << zero;
    cin>>ans
        if (ans == 0)
        {
            score = score + 1;
            goto start;
        }
        else
    goto start;
}
if (x == 1)
{
    cout << one;
    goto start;
}
```

The way im trying to do it is putting the minimum amount of numbers somewhere, then the computer pulls a group of them out and prints them, then the user enters the numeral and if they are correct their score goes up.

e.g

-Output:hundertsechsundzwanzig
-Input:126
correct

Comment: Can you please at least show us some example of a session running your program? For example showing a few lines of input and output? And how do you store the words, how do you select a word? And please try to show us at least *some* code, preferably and if possible a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried this problem yourself?

Comment: Easiest way is to have a list of words and then random pick one instead of trying to generate them.

Comment: Please don't use labels and `goto` instead of loops. Especially since your "loop" reinitializes the random number generator and the variables (which should not be in the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other languages I know there is some logic to how the numbers are put together in German. For example "sechs und dreißig", "sechs und zwanzig" etc. Very much like the English "thirty six" and "twenty six", just the order of the numbers are a little different.

That means you can easily solve your problem by having *three* random numbers (each between `0` and `9`) and use them each as an index into three arrays. Perhaps something like this:

```
std::string const hundreds[10] = {
    "",
    "hundert",
    "zweihundert",
    // etc...
};

std::string const tens[10] = {
    "",
    "",  // Special case for the tens
    "und swanzig",
    "und dreißig",
    // etc...
}

std::string const ones[10] = {
    "null",
    "ein",
    "zwei",
    // etc...
};

unsigned hundred_digit = get_random_number_between_0_and_9();
unsigned ten_digit = get_random_number_between_0_and_9();
unsigned one_digit = get_random_number_between_0_and_9();

std::string number = hundreds[hundred_digit] + ' ' + ones[one_digit] + ' ' + tens[ten_digit];
```

As mentioned in a comment above, if `ten_digit` is `1` then you need some special handling for that. Can still solve it with an array though. A special case if the `one_digit` is zero could be useful too, as well as other corner cases. But hopefully you will get the general gist of it all.